# while true statement looping in python

Tags: python

```
inta=int(input("enter the first number"))
intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
intc=int(input("enter your second number"))

while True:

    if intb == '+' :
        print(inta+intc)
        break
    if intb == '-' :
        print(inta-intc)
        break
    if intb == '*' :
        print(inta*intc)
        break
    else:
        print("error try again")
```

Hello, I am new to programming and I have discovered a problem. I am building a calculator and I am trying to use an else statement to keep the loop going incase the user enters something they shouldn't however when I do this, the printed statement keeps on looping, how can I fix this?

Comment: put your input in your while loop, otherwise it will use the same (previous) input during the whole loop. You can also add add a `q` or `quit` option to get out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the `intb` variable to something that waits for the user to input a correct value in the while statement.

You can make the first lines a function, and call it back. If it enter the else, it might do the job in your case.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp if you are new to python you can use this website as a base for basic comprehension

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the value of `intb` after you have rejected its current value. You need to repeat the call to `input` *inside* the loop.

```
inta=int(input("enter the first number"))
intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
intc=int(input("enter your second number"))

while True:

    if intb == '+' :
        print(inta+intc)
        break
    if intb == '-' :
        print(inta-intc)
        break
    if intb == '*' :
        print(inta*intc)
        break
    else:
        print("error try again")
        tb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
```

You'll probably want separate loops for *each* input, to accommodate non-integer inputs for the operands. Once the values of `inta`, `intb`, and `intc` are confirmed valid, *then* you can do the requested operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your variable inside the loop. This should work -

```
inta=int(input("enter the first number"))
while True:
    intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
    if intb == '+' :
        print(inta+intc)
        break
    if intb == '-' :
        print(inta-intc)
        break
    if intb == '*' :
        print(inta*intc)
        break
    else:
        print("error try again")
intc=int(input("enter the second number"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track. The problem is that your loop isn't giving the user a chance to change their selection if they've made a mistake. If you move your input code into the loop as well, it should work out fine.

```
while True:
    inta(input("enter the first number"))
    intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
    intc=int(input("enter your second number"))

    if intb == '+' :
        print(inta+intc)
        break
    if intb == '-' :
        print(inta-intc)
        break
    if intb == '*' :
        print(inta*intc)
        break
    else:
        print("error try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here is to handle it using an exception. This way you can try converting the input to an int afterwards. If an error occurs, the code goes from the "try" branch to the "except" branch.

You can create a custom exception if the mode of operation is not in the accepted list of values.

```
#Forever
while True:
    
    #Get inputs
    inta = input("enter the first number")
    intb = input("enter mode")
    intc = input("enter the second number")
    
    try:
        
        #Try to convert to ints
        inta = int(inta)
        intc = int(intc)
        
        #Check if valid mode in list
        if not intb in ["-","+","*"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid mode input. Please try again.")
    
        #Perform operation
        if intb in ["-"]:
            print(inta-intc)
        elif intb in ["+"]:
            print(inta+intc)
        elif intb in ["*"]:
            print(inta*intc)
        
    #Handle exception
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

`while True:` will always be true, it literally cannot ever not be true, so it will loop forever. You need to ask for input and verify it within the `while` loop, then do the calculation outside the `while` loop.

For example,

```
inta=int(input("enter the first number"))

inputValid == False
while inputValid == False:
  intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
  if intb == '+' or intb == '-' or intb == '*':
    inputValid = True
  else:
    print("error try again")

intc=int(input("enter your second number"))

#the rest of your code
if intb == '+' :
    print(inta+intc)
    break
if intb == '-' :
    print(inta-intc)
    break
if intb == '*' :
    print(inta*intc)
    break
```

If you want it to loop and ask for calculations repeatedly then you'll need a second `while` loop containing your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is asking for the input inside the loop. Since you don't want the code to loop within the `else` condition, asking for the input every time the while loop restarts might be what you want to do.

```
while True:
    inta=int(input("enter the first number"))
    intb=input('enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product')
    intc=int(input("enter your second number"))
    if intb == '+' :
        print(inta+intc)
        break
    elif intb == '-' :
        print(inta-intc)
        break
    elif intb == '*' :
        print(inta*intc)
        break
    else:
        print("error try again")
```

This should work. Using this, when the user enters something that does not match any of the conditions, it'll once print `error try again`, and then restart asking  for the input for variable `inta`.

P.S. Using `if` again and again will cause the interpreter to check each and every condition. Using `elif`, you can check for the first matched condition. There are cases where you need to use `if` statements, but for this one, using `elif` is better. (The first conditional statement has to be `if`, like in this one)

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters suggested, you need to include an `input` in the `while` loop to provide an opportunity to change the operator if required, otherwise you get an endless loop that checks `intb` without a way to change it.

The most straightforward fix would look like this:

```
inta = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
intc = int(input('Enter your second number: '))

while True:
    intb = input('Enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product: ')

    if intb == '+':
        print(inta + intc)
        break
    if intb == '-':
        print(inta - intc)
        break
    if intb == '*':
        print(inta * intc)
        break
    else:
        print('Error; try again')
```

Here is a more advanced solution to preserve the order of inputting the operands and the operator:

```
import operator

inta = int(input('Enter the first number: '))

while True:
    intb = input('Enter + for addition, - for subtraction, * for product: ')

    if intb == '+':
        op = operator.add
        break
    if intb == '-':
        op = operator.sub
        break
    if intb == '*':
        op = operator.mul
        break
    else:
        print('Error; try again')


intc = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
print(op(inta, intc))
```

P. S. The examples above have been reformatted according to the Style Guide for Python Code (feel free to learn about it here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).